# How do I select random rows from a database -- With a twist?

Tags: sql-server, random

Assume (highly anonymized):

```
Create Table myTable
(
ID INT PK,
INDEXNUMBER INT,
VERSION INT,
Data VARCHAR(MAX)
)
```

This table is used to store mutually exclusive data.
For example:

```
100 1 1 BOB
217 1 2 JOHN
319 1 3 GEORGE
420 7 1 MARY
415 7 2 SUSAN
```

In this case, I need to randomly pick ONE of BOB, JOHN or GEORGE and ONE of MARY or SUSAN.

I'm happy with either the ID or the `INDEXNUMBER/VERSION` pair.

If it helps to think about it,  it's like picking a single shift of a hockey team from a table containing a roster:

Pick 1 Center from 3 available,
Pick 1 Left Wing from 5 available, etc.

I've been playing with `NEWID()` and `MAX/MIN` (Cast `NEWID` to `varchar` first) but I keep getting hung up on the `GROUP BY`.  If I `GROUP BY ID`, then max is operating on a single row at a time, yielding the entire table.

If I `GROUP BY INDEXNUMBER, VERSION` I get a similar result (The pair being unique).

What I need to do is `GROUP BY INDEXNUMBER` (excluding `ID` from the query entirely) yet somehow retrieve the `VERSION`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partition by the `INDEXNUMBER` (I'm assuming that you need one from each though it's not specifically stated) and order by `NEWID()`

```
SELECT ID
FROM (
    SELECT 
        Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY INDEXNUMBER ORDER BY NEWID()) Sort,
        ID, 
        Data
    FROM myTable
) s
WHERE Sort = 1
```

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/87806/2)

Answer (score 0):

Solution is simple, join data with temp table.
Please see my sample code:

```
--drop temp table if exists...
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempData') is not null
begin
 drop table #tempData
end
go

--select distinct INDEXNUMBER and fill temp table...
select distinct INDEXNUMBER into #tempData
from myTable
go

--join temp table with actual data to get randon rows...
select T.INDEXNUMBER,
(
  select top 1 VERSION 
  from myTable where 
  INDEXNUMBER=T.INDEXNUMBER 
  order by NEWID()
) 'Version'
from #tempData T
```

This syntax is suitable for SQL Server. Happy coding!